# how to get records in search query with date range and search fields like '%xyz%'?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This my SQL query

```
SELECT *
FROM `newleads` 
WHERE (ORGANISATIONNAME LIKE "%sa%" AND LEADID LIKE "%%" OR (CONTACTTIME >= "2016-05-02" AND CONTACTTIME < "2019-05-17")) AND
       STATUS = 0
```

I have to search Organization name like SA but in date range 
but I am getting records having organization name like sa but not mentioned date range.
if my date range would be empty or not selected then result will show above case

can we write in such a way?

WHERE (ORGANISATIONNAME LIKE "%sa%" AND LEADID LIKE "%%" AND (CONTACTTIME LIKE "%2016-05-02%" ) AND STATUS = 0

so if somwetime date will not selected then it will take all SA results

or

WHERE (ORGANISATIONNAME LIKE "%sa%" AND LEADID LIKE "%%" AND (CONTACTTIME LIKE "%(between "fromdate" AND "todate")%" ) AND STATUS = 0

or

where (ORGANISATIONNAME LIKE "%sa%" AND LEADID LIKE "%%" OR (CONTACTTIME BETWEEN (CONTACTTIME LIKE "%fromdate%" AND CONTACTTIME LIKE "%todate%"))) AND STATUS = "0"

Comment: Please describe the logic that you really need.  Sample data and desired results are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you need "sa" organizations and the date range, then I would expect a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `newleads` 
WHERE ORGANISATIONNAME LIKE '%sa%' AND
      STATUS = 0 AND
      CONTACTTIME >= '2018-05-02' AND CONTACTTIME < '2018-05-17';
```

The standard SQL delimiter for string and date constants is the single quote, which is why I changed the double quotes to single quotes.  MySQL does allow double quotes.  I generally consider that a bad practice, because double quotes have other uses (such as escaping identifier names).

Comment: @mickmackusa . . . MySQL allows double quotes for string and date constants.  So, no, this should not be closed for that reason.

Comment: Ok.  I'd like to see some backticks around the keyword `STATUS` if you would oblige. Would you use `BETWEEN` here?

Comment: @mickmackusa . . . `status` is not a MySQL reserved word (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).  Unnecessary backticks just pollute queries, in my opinion.

Comment: I just looked that up before commenting.  Am I looking at the wrong docs? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-S

Comment: @mickmackusa . . . The documentation is a bit confusing.  An "R" next to the word means that you need to escape the value.